# Hibernate Criteria to get maximum ID of the child of one-to-many for each parent entity

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have two classes:

```
public class DocumentRecord {  

    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(...)
    @JoinColumn(name = "document_id")
    private final List<DocumentHistRecord> history = new ArrayList<>();

    ... other fields
}
```

and

```
public class DocumentHistRecord {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    ... other fields
}
```

What I want is to have the maximum id of the DocumentHistRecord attached to every document. Every Document has at least one DocumentHistRecord in its history.

How to achieve that in Hibernate 4.3.7 with the Hibernate Criteria API?

Here is an example of the tables and the result I want:

```
Table DocumentRecord:      Table DocumentHistRecord
id                         id  |  documentId
--                         -----------------
1                          1   |  1
2                          2   |  1
3                          3   |  1
4                          4   |  2
                           5   |  3
                           6   |  3
                           7   |  4
                           8   |  4
```

The result would be:

```
id (from DocumentHistRecord table)
--
3
4
6
8
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would look like this :

```
final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(DocumentRecord.class);
criteria.createCriteria("history" ,"h");


ProjectionList pl = Projections.projectionList();
pl.add(Projections.groupProperty("id"));
pl.add(Projections.max("h.id"));
criteria.setProjection(pl);
List res = criteria.list();
```

Comment: @BalusC : I know that Hibernate is now an implementation of JPA API and you are right about the confusing TAGs in the formulation. But I really wanted a Hibernate API solution.

Comment: @jpprade : Thank you for your answer and she seems correct. I will test is on Monday